# two fluid divs in the same line - right div with min-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make two fluid divs in the same line.

I want the right div to have a min-width of 275px,and the left div to always fill the gap so both of them together will be 100% width of their container div.

Comment: good idea. do it. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-right-menu.htm

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gVFF6/)**

**css**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    background-color:Gray;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.div1{
    float:left;
}
.div2{
    width:275px;
    min-width:275px;
    float:right;
}
```

--

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/gVFF6/1/)**

Comment: I want the right div(div2) to be able to be more then 275px,but not less then 275px.